# Creating graphics objects that never overlap java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm making a small balloon game in java and trying to write my code, so that when I create new 'balloon' objects they don't overlap on the screen.

The code I have so far is:

```
 public void newGame(){
    UI.clearGraphics();
    this.currentScore = 0;
    this.totalPopped = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.balloons.length-1; i++) {
        this.balloons[i] = new Balloon(50 + Math.random()*400, 50 + Math.random()*400);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < this.balloons.length; j++) {
            if (this.balloons[i] !=null && this.balloons[j] != null && this.balloons[i].isTouching(balloons[j])) {
                this.balloons[j] = new Balloon(50 + Math.random()*400, 50+ Math.random()*400);
            }
        }
        this.balloons[i].draw();
    }
    UI.printMessage("New game: click on a balloon.  High score = "+this.highScore);
}
```

using the draw and isTouching methods:

```
    public void draw(){
    UI.setColor(color);
    UI.fillOval(centerX-radius, centerY-radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    if (!this.popped){
        UI.setColor(Color.black);
        UI.drawOval(centerX-radius, centerY-radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    }
}

    /** Returns true if this Balloon is touching the other balloon, and false otherwise
 *  Returns false if either balloon is popped. */
public boolean isTouching(Balloon other){
    if (this.popped || other.popped) return false;
    double dx = other.centerX - this.centerX;
    double dy = other.centerY - this.centerY;
    double dist = other.radius + this.radius;
    return (Math.hypot(dx,dy) < dist);
}
```

how can I write this, so that when the balloons are created, none of them are touching each other?

Comment: You could simply calculate the bounding Rectangle of the ballon and use the intersects method to determine if they overlap

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have two loops. In the first loop the balloons are created. In the second loop, every balloon is tested against every other loop. Do this test in the first loop: after creating a new balloon, test it against all already existing balloons.

Comment: I thought about this but didn't think it would work, how can i write the code for the first iteration of the loop when only one balloon has been created?

Comment: When only one balloon has been created there is no other balloon to test it against. So a simple `if` clause should handle this case.

Comment: I guess I should just use an if statement to check for null.. correct?

Comment: I'm now facing the problem where at least one of the indexes is null throughout the whole for loop, how can i fix this?

Comment: How can an `int` ever be `null`. It can be `0` but this a perfectly legal index into an array.

Comment: Sorry I mean the there is no object at that index, i starts at 0 in the outer loop and j starts at i + 1 in the inner loop. The if statement in the inner loop checks if i and j are not null, but j is always null